# gitlab in docker behind traefik proxy fails (usually)

Tags: docker, gitlab-omnibus, traefik

I have several web sites running in docker with LetsEncrypt credentials and routed via traefik.
I would like to run a local gitlab-ce in docker similarly with LetsEncrypt and traefik.

So I added this to my traefik.toml file:

```
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "gitlab.mydomain.com"
```

And this to config/gitlab.rb:

```
external_url "http://gitlab.mydomain.com"
```

And I start gitlab with:

```
docker run -d --restart=always \
     --hostname gitlab.mydomain.com \
     --expose 80 \
     --volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
     --volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
     --volume /var/log/gitlab:/var/log/gitlab \
     --label traefik.frontend.rule=Host:gitlab.mydomain.com \
     --name gitlab gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

Going to https://gitlab.mydomain.com/ I get a secure site with a LetsEncrypt generated certificate, but the site doesn't load:

> Internal Server Error

When I reload the page I see this in `docker logs gitlab -f`:

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/sshd/current <==
2017-02-12_16:51:31.00446 Bad protocol version identification 'GET / HTTP/1.1' from 172.17.0.8 port 41138
2017-02-12_16:51:31.26238 Bad protocol version identification 'GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1' from 172.17.0.8 port 41140
```

Searching for `/error/i` in the logs I see several things that could be issues (lots of errors reported in zruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.2.2z) but no "smoking gun" AFAICT.

And to top off the craziness, about every ten or so (random) times that I run `docker restart gitlab` the site comes up perfectly. I've been tempted to just leave it up, but therein lies madness...

How can I get it to come up reliably? Or how can I debug this more completely?

Comment: Try changing `http` to `https`. Have adjusted the `gitlab.rb` to point to the proper certificates?

Comment: Thanks - I've tried both `http` and `https` and have pointed gitlab at self-signed certs, but the only times the gitlab site has (randomly) come up is with `http`. This matches how traefik and LetsEncrypt work (and even when not up gitlab is showing "Secure" in the browser toolbar with the LetsEncrypt cert).

Comment: I have a similar problem in kubernetes envinment (ingress traefik). With `GITLAB_HTTPS=false` settings, it is always success, but `GITLAB_HTTPS=true` never success.

Answer (score 32):

This answer probably comes way too late for you, but I ran into the same issue and was able to solve it.

The important clue is that the log errors are by the `sshd` daemon!

Traefik will, by default, pick the *first port* exposed by the container (by the Dockerfile, not the ports you manually expose!).
In case of the Gitlab container, this is the *ssh* port 22.

So Traefik will direct the web requests to Gitlab's SSH daemon.

To fix this, you need to set the port for Traefik explicitly, with a label:

`Traefik 1.x`:

```
labels:
    ...
    - traefik.port=80
```

`Traefik 2.x`:

```
labels:
    - traefik.http.services.<your-service-name>.loadbalancer.server.port=80
```

Comment: The label for traefik 2.1 is:  

`traefik.http.services.<your-service-name>.loadbalancer.server.port=80`

Comment: With traefik >=2.2.1 it has to be `traefik.http.services.<your-service-name>.loadbalancer.server.port=80`

Answer (score 1):

i've used [sameersbn's docker-compose](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab) and added the following docker-compose.override.yml in the same directory.

```
version: "2"

services:
    gitlab:
      labels:
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:git.schulz.codes"
        - "traefik.port=80"
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https"
```

this keeps working quiet nicely with the following traefik docker-compose

```
version: "2"

services:
  proxy:
    restart: always
    image: traefik
    container_name: traefik
    command: --web --docker --docker.domain=docker.localhost --logLevel=DEBUG
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./data:/etc/traefik/acme:rw
```

and this traefik.toml

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]
[acme]
email = "yourmail@domain.com"
storageFile = "/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
OnHostRule = true
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "domain.com"
  sans = ["gitlab.domain.com"]
[web]
address = ":8080"
[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "docker.localhost"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = true
```