# How to setup Gitlab-ce on docker swarm behind Traefik?

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-swarm, traefik, gitlab-omnibus

My question may seem really similar to some others and i'm new so reputation is not enough to add to comment to :

[gitlab in docker behind traefik proxy fails (usually)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192934/gitlab-in-docker-behind-traefik-proxy-fails-usually)

I will try to be specific :

- Traefik won't forward ssh request because it is not HTTP.
- I want Gitlab-ce on a vps, to which I usually connect with ssh.
- Is it ok to expose Gitlab to a free port on my server to listen to ssh connections ? No confusions between command to enter the vps and command to push to Gitlab ?