# traefik send http over wrong port to gitlab

Tags: docker, gitlab, traefik

I'm setting up a gitlab server behind traefik proxy, but my gitlab sshd logs says traefik send http request over 22 port to gitlab, causing Internal server error.

```
 ==> /var/log/gitlab/sshd/current <==
gitlab    | 2019-08-27_03:39:15.42508 Bad protocol version identification 'GET / HTTP/1.1' from 192.168.144.2 port 33462
```

I found there is a similar discuss [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192934/gitlab-in-docker-behind-traefik-proxy-fails-usually), however the answer did not work, is there any way to change gitlab backend from 22 to 80?

The following is my code and configs.

```
# traefik docker-compose.yaml
version: '3'
services: 
  traefik:
    container_name: traefik
    image: traefik
    command: --api
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
    networks:
      - web
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

```
# traefik.toml
debug = false
logLevel = "INFO"
defaultEntryPoints = ["http","https"]

[entryPoints]
[entryPoints.http]
address = ":80"

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "mydomain.com"
watch = true
exposedByDefault = false
```

```
# gitlab docker-compose.yaml
version: '3'
services:
  # expose 22 80 443
  gitlab:
    container_name: gitlab
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ee
    volumes:
      - /nsrv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab
      - /nsrv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab
      - /nsrv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:gitlab.mydomain.com
      - traefik.prot=80
    networks:
      - web
    restart: always   

networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo in your gitlab docker-compose.yaml file.

Replace traefik.prot by traefik.port and it should work better.

Comment: Oh, I must be dizzy on that day. After I revising the typo, everything works great. Thank you very much!